# Query not show Account Name and COmpany Name as expected

Tags: php, mysql

I have this situation when I run a query:

```
ACCOUNT
-----------
account_id  account_name
1           STARCLASS
2           STEPWAY


COMPANY
-----------
company_id     company_account_id     company_name
1              1                      STORE 01
2              2                      STORE 01
3              2                      STORE 02


RESUME
-----------
resume_id  resume_company_id  resume_start_date   resume_end_date    resume_total
1          1                  2017-01-01          2017-01-31         300.00
2          2                  2017-01-01          2017-01-31         147.00
3          3                  2017-01-01          2017-01-31         50.00


QUERY
-----------
SELECT *
FROM resume
LEFT JOIN company ON company_id = resume_company_id
LEFT JOIN account ON account_id = company_account_id
GROUP BY account_id

WHILE
-----------
while ($i < $num) {
.......
$account_name = mysql_result($result,$i,"account_name");
$company_name = mysql_result($result,$i,"company_name");
.......


QUERY RESULTS
-----------
ID    company_name              account_name    resume_start_date   resume_end_date    resume_total
1     STORE 01                  STARCLASS       2017-01-01          2017-01-31         300.00
2     STORE 01                  STEPWAY         2017-01-01          2017-01-31         147.00
3     **NOT SHOW COMPANY NAME**                 2017-01-01          2017-01-31         50.00
      **AND ACCOUNT NAME**
```

When I group by ACCOUNT_ID last line variables liks account_name and company_name appears blank.

There is a way to solve?
Any tip about this?

Thanks all for helping

Comment: It's almost never right to `GROUP BY` a column from a table you're joining with `LEFT JOIN`. All the rows with no match for that column will have the same `NULL` value for it, so they'll all be grouped together.

Comment: Why are you grouping by `account_id` when you don't use any aggregation functions? This will just pick the other columns from random rows in that group.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cef05/1

Comment: Why do you have 3 rows of results? There are only 2 `account_id`s, so you should only get 2 results. How do you set `$num`? Why don't you use `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))` to get the rows, instead of `mysql_result` (which won't port to `mysqli` or `PDO`)?

Answer (score 0):

Expressions that are not being passed through an aggregate function should be included. As well, I'm not sure what software package versions you are using, but my results only include two rows.

Either

1. You meant to use ORDER BY rather than GROUP BY. GROUP BY is primarily intended to apply an aggregate on a "group" of rows (e.g. SELECT SUM(`resume_total`) .... GROUP BY `account_id`).
2. Your SQL (which is non-compliant) is creating a bug where the results of the LEFT JOIN clauses are being grouped, while your `SELECT * FROM resume` is still being fulfilled (3 records but only two records worth of values for the LEFT JOIN values).
3. Something else.

Either use ORDER BY if you want the listing to be in order, or GROUP BY with selected expressions or aggregate functions.